# Resample function throwing error with Twitter Data

Tags: python, twitter, pandas

I have some twitter data

```
tweetText   tweetSource      tweetCreated
#Tweet...   TwitterforAND    2015-10-15 06:52:34
#Tweet...   TwitterforAND    2015-10-15 06:52:34
#Tweet...   TwitterforiPH    2015-10-15 06:52:34
```

I then want to resampe this data into a time series to analyse tweets per minute. I firstly verify 'TweetCreated' is in datetime format:

```
df.tweetCreated.dtypes()
ln[1] tweetCreated       datetime64[ns]
```

Just to be sure i format tweetCreated as datetime

```
 df["tweetCreated"] = pd.to_datetime(df["tweetCreated"], unit='s')
```

I then try to resample for analysis

```
rs= df['tweetCreated'].resample('1t', how='count')
```

And get the following error

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

However I can clearly see from my dtypes analysis tweetCreated is datetime. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your `tweetCreated` created column *must* be the index of the dataframe you're working with if you want to use `resample()`.

You can do that by `df.set_index(['tweetCreated'], inplace=True)`